# REST API multiple errors response best practice

Tags: rest, validation, error-handling, api-design, software-design

I'm building a rest api using Express with the following architecture:

`Routes->Validation(Joi)->Controller->Service->Model(Mongoose)`

Now, I'm trying to find the best way to send errors to client. I thought about sending a json with an array of errors like this:

```
"errors": [
        {
            "code":"PRODUCT_ID.INVALID",
            "message":"Invalid productId",
            "pointer":"/device/productId"

        },
        {
            "code":"VARIANT_ID.INVALID",
            "message":"Invalid variantId",
            "pointer":"/device/variantId"
        }
    ]
```

But I have found a problem, because when the error is thrown from the model, for example when a PATCH request is sent with an id not in db, I don't have the reference in the model to the specific request field that is causing the error, so I can't build the pointer and the correct code.
I really can't figure it out how to handle this, so thanks for any help.